# OpenShift route to return a 308 Permanent Redirect

Tags: openshift, haproxy, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-308

If I set an OpenShift route with `insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy` to `Redirect`.
Client will  be able to redirect `http` to `https`.

They will receive a `302 Found` (temporary redirection).

Does route offer the the possibility to tune this behavior and returns a `308 Permanent Redirect` instead (or `301`)?